# Выбор вида службы для приложения

Tags: android, android-service

Пишу фитнес приложение, в функционал которого входит шагомер. Нужно чтобы он работал все время, даже если приложение закрыто. Но не могу понять какую из разновидностей сервиса использовать: обычный или привязанный или возможно реализовать как-то совсем иначе. Сервис будет считывать через сенсор менеджер шаги и отправлять иногда данные бд. Буду рад любому совету или подсказке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сейчас Google запрещает использовать любой **Background Service** длительное время. Это связано с тем, что многие приложения производили свою деятельность и пользователь ничего не знал об этом. Так что любой Background Service умрет достаточно быстро после смерти приложения.

Если же вам необходимо работать независимо от того запущено ли приложение. То вы должны использовать Foreground Service.

**Foreground Service** – это сервис, о котором пользователь осведомлен. Это достигается с помощью отображения нотификации в статус-баре.
Пример foreground сервиса – отображение нотификации при проигрывании музыки в приложении-плеере.

Более подробно о сервисах вы можете почитать в [документации Google](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services).

А [здесь](https://medium.com/@ramkumarv3/foreground-service-with-notification-channel-ac6697c8a6d1) можете посмотреть пример его использования.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку! Заметил, что вы ответили почти на все вопросы задаваемые мной, спасибо вам.